# How do I call a method that has a method as its argument?

Tags: java, methods

Here is a piece of code I have: (what I am trying to do with it is: define a method "renamingrule" in my main class, instantiate a instance of my other class "renamescript"  and call its rename method passing as a parameter the "renamingrule" method i've defined in the main class. Everything is well in the RenamScript class, no errors, but i dont know how to call the rename method of the script class from my main class/method. thanks)

```
public class RenameScript2 {

    ...

    public void rename(Method methodToCall) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {


    try
    {
        ...

            String command = "cmd /c rename "+_path+"\\"+"\""+next_file+"\" "
                    +"\""+methodToCall.invoke(next_file, next_index)+"\"";
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    }catch(IOException e1) {} catch(IllegalAccessException IA1) {}  catch(InvocationTargetException IT1) {} ;


    }//end of rename


} //end of class
//=======================================

public class RenameScriptMain2 {

    public static String RenamingRule(String input, int file_row)
    {
        String output = "renamed file "+(file_row+1)+".mp3";
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        RenameScript2 renamer = new RenameScript2();
        renamer.setPath("c:\\users\\roise\\documents\\netbeansprojects\\temp\\files");
        try{
            renamer.rename(RenamingRule);
        }catch(IOException e2) {};

        System.out.println("Done from main()\n\n");

    }
} //end of class
```

Answer (score 5):

You get hold of the `Method` object through `Class.getMethod` method. Something like this:

```
RenameScript2.class.getMethod("rename", parameters);
```

---

However, I suggest you consider writing an interface for a class that can perform the renaming, instead of passing a `Method`.

Such interface could look like

```
interface RenameAction {
    void performRename();
}
```

To wrap the script in a `RenameAction` object you would do something like

```
RenameAction action = new RenameAction() {
    void performRename() {
        // ...
        String command = "cmd /c rename "+_path+"\\"+"\""+next_file+"\" "...
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        // ...
    }
};
```

You would then simply do like this:

```
public void rename(RenameAction action) {
    action.performRename();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, aioobe is definitely correct, passing a Method object is a little ugly.  I'll assume that you're stuck with it!

To get a method, you'll need to use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).  The below code grabs the method called `toString` on the class `Integer`.  It then invokes the `toString` method.

```
Method method = Integer.class.getMethod("toString");
Object o = method.invoke(new Integer(7));
System.out.println(o);
```

Static methods don't need to pass the first parameter to `method.invoke`

```
Method method = File.class.getMethod("listRoots");
System.out.println(method.invoke(null));
```

This shows the reason why you shouldn't use it.  That string "toString" and "listRoots" are not refactorable.  If someone renames a method, then instead of a compile-time error, you'll get a runtime exception thrown (hence the exceptions you'll need to catch, `NoSuchMethodException` and `IllegalAccessException`).  It's also much slower to use reflection than to use normal code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should do:

1. Make class `RenameScript2` abstract by adding an abstract method `public static String RenamingRule(String input, int file_row)`
2. Then have your main class `RenameScriptMain2` extend above class `RenameScript2` and provide implementation of the method `RenamingRule()`.
3. Now inside `main` method create instance of the class `RenameScriptMain2` and call method `RenamingRule()`